# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property when using useRef() in React Native(Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

[image]I'm trying to use a useRef hook so a scrollview and my pan gesture handler can share a common ref. but once I initialize the useRef() hook and pass it to both components, it breaks with this error

`TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.`

I've tried typecasting and adding types to the useRef call but it returns the same error. Can someone help please?

My component:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  PanGestureHandlerProps,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, {
  runOnJS,
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export interface InfluencerItemProps
  extends Pick<PanGestureHandlerProps, "simultaneousHandlers"> {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  userName: string;
  profileImg: string;
  rating?: Number;
  onDismiss?: (Item: InfluencerItemProps) => void;
}

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 65;

const { width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get("window");
const TRANSLATE_X_THRESHOLD = -SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.3;

const InfluencerItem = (props: InfluencerItemProps) => {
  const { name, userName, profileImg, onDismiss, simultaneousHandlers } = props;

  const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
  const marginVertical = useSharedValue("2%");
  const R_Height = useSharedValue(ITEM_HEIGHT);
  const opacity = useSharedValue(1);

  const panGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent>({
    onActive: (event) => {
      translateX.value = event.translationX;
    },
    onEnd: () => {
      const shouldbeDismissed = translateX.value < TRANSLATE_X_THRESHOLD;
      if (shouldbeDismissed) {
        translateX.value = withTiming(-SCREEN_WIDTH);
        R_Height.value = withTiming(0);
        marginVertical.value = withTiming("0%");
        opacity.value = withTiming(0, undefined, (isFinished) => {
          if (isFinished && onDismiss) {
            runOnJS(onDismiss)(props);
          }
        });
      } else {
        translateX.value = withTiming(0);
      }
    },
  });

  const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: translateX.value,
      },
    ],
  }));

  const rIconContainerStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const opacity = withTiming(
      translateX.value < TRANSLATE_X_THRESHOLD ? 1 : 0
    );

    return { opacity };
  });

  const RContainerStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      height: R_Height.value,
      opacity: opacity.value,
      marginVertical: marginVertical.value,
    };
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper, RContainerStyle]}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.iconContainer, rIconContainerStyle]}>
        <FontAwesome name="trash" size={ITEM_HEIGHT * 0.5} color="white" />
      </Animated.View>
      <PanGestureHandler
        simultaneousHandlers={simultaneousHandlers}
        onGestureEvent={panGesture}
      >
        <Animated.View style={[styles.container, rStyle]}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: profileImg,
            }}
            style={styles.image}
          />
          <View style={styles.text}>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default InfluencerItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 12,
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
  image: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: "4%",
    height: 48,
    width: 48,
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  text: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    marginHorizontal: 6,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "#121212",
  },
  userName: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "400",
    color: "#121212",
  },
  iconContainer: {
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    width: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    position: "absolute",
    right: "2.5%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

InfluencerItem.defaultProps = {
  name: "UserName",
  userName: "userName",
  profileImg:
    "https://d2qp0siotla746.cloudfront.net/img/use-cases/profile-picture/template_0.jpg",
  rating: "4",
};
```

This is my Screen:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import InfluencerItem from "../../components/InfluencerItem";
import { InfluencerItemProps } from "../../components/InfluencerItem";
// import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

type Props = {};

const Saved = (props: Props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  const [influencerData, setInfluencerData] = useState(influencerz);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    console.log(search);
  };

  const onDismiss = useCallback((Item: InfluencerItemProps) => {
    setInfluencerData((influencers) =>
      influencers.filter((item) => item.id !== Item.id)
    );
  }, []);

  const ref = useRef(null); //useRef initialization

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.saved}>
          {/* Saved Kikos component goes in here */}

          <ScrollView ref={ref}> //passed ref here
            {influencerData.map((influencer) => (
              <InfluencerItem
                key={influencer.id}
                name={influencer.name}
                userName={influencer.handle}
                profileImg={influencer.image}
                onDismiss={onDismiss}
                simultaneousHandlers={ref} //also passed ref here
              />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.bottomText}>No Saved Kikos again</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Saved;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: "4%",
  },
  headerText: {
    color: "#121212",
    fontWeight: "700",
    lineHeight: 30,
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  search: {
    borderRadius: 12,
    backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9",
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 21,
    color: "#7A7B7C",
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 5,
    height: 45,
    marginTop: 15,
    position: "relative",
  },
  innerSearch: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 30,
    right: 10,
  },
  saved: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.15)",
    marginTop: 22,
    paddingVertical: "7%",
    marginBottom: 34,
  },
  bottomText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "500",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Which line produces the error?

Comment: you have to use a generic for useRef : `const ref = useRef<TypeOfRef | null>(null)` otherwise don't provide a default value :   `const ref = useRef()`

Comment: the error is in the scrollview where I map through an array and render the InfluencerItem component. That's where I pass the refs to the scrollview and the component (reason for the error)

Comment: what type of ref would I have to infer then. A scrollview? or React.MutableObject?

Answer (score 0):

Use `createRef()` instead of `useRef()` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/common-gh/#simultaneoushandlers).

```
const imagePinch = React.createRef();

return (
  <RotationGestureHandler
    simultaneousHandlers={imagePinch}
    ....
```

There is a complete example [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/main/example/src/recipes/scaleAndRotate/index.tsx) in TypeScript.

Also make sure to use `Animated` version of components wherever applicable (`<Animated.View>` instead of `<View>`, `<Animated.Image>` instead of `<Image>` etc)